# DRY, is there a better gradle dependency declaration?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

is there a better way to declare multiple packages (e.g. 'appcompat-v7') from the same group (e.g. 'com.android.support') with the same version (e.g. '23.4.0')?

actual declaration:

```
...
def androidSupport = '23.4.0'
def rxBinding = '0.4.0'

dependencies {
    ...

    // android support
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$androidSupport"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$androidSupport"
    compile "com.android.support:percent:$androidSupport"

    // rxJava
    compile "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:$rxBinding"
    compile "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-support-v4:$rxBinding"
    compile "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:$rxBinding"
    compile "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-design:$rxBinding"
    compile "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-recyclerview-v7:$rxBinding"
...
```

is it possible to do something like that?:

```
...
compile(group: 'com.android.support', version: '23.4.0') {
    modules: "appcompat-v7", "design", "percent" 
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you realize that a Gradle build script is just a Groovy script, which means that each of those "compile" lines are just method calls, you start to see many possibilities.

For instance, specify an "inline" array of artifact names, call "each()" on that, and pass a closure that specifies "`compile group:$it:$version`" (or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

```
def multiArtifactDependency = { String group, String version, List<String> artifacts -> artifacts.each { compile "${group}:${it}:${version}" } }

multiArtifactDependency('com.android.support', '23.3.0', ['appcompat-v7', 'design'])
multiArtifactDependency('com.squareup.retrofit2', '2.0.2', ['retrofit', 'converter-gson', 'adapter-rxjava'])
```